# How to use React.js class/library in Angular2/ts file

Tags: reactjs, angular7

I have a angular component in which I am trying to use/refer react.js file which returns HTML/DOM from render() method of it. Any Idea how to handle it in angular7

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that it's always good to add more details to your question, plus what you've tried so far with code.